In Twin Peaks, what does Catherine mean by "Are you an ambitious man, Mr Nev?"
In the episode Realization Time, Catherine discovers the existence of a life insurance policy and the following exchange takes place:

MR. NEV I have to admit I thought it a little ... unusual. Life
insurance when the client is too busy ... to be involved. (smiling) I
mean, you did know about this policy didn’t you?
CATHERINE Are you suggesting that there’s something ... irregular at
work here?
MR. NEV I certainly never got that idea from Mrs. Packard, no. Or from
Mr. Horne for that matter either. When he offered to collect your
signatures I thought it was fine. Just with a new account, I like to
be certain to (gestures with the pen as if to cross a ‘T’) cross every
‘T’.
(Again he shows her where to sign on the document.)
MR. NEV Right here please.
CATHERINE You know, I’m noticing that there’s some ... minor changes
that I asked my attorney to make that are not included in this draft.
I think what I’d like to do is go over this with him on the phone in
the morning, and initial the changes and get the completed documents
to you at that time.
MR. NEV If there’s anything that I can do to help you ... with the
policy or anything at all?
CATHERINE (staring at him with a straight face) Are you an ambitious
man Mr. Nev?
MR. NEV One likes to think so.
CATHERINE One never knows. There may be a few ‘T’s left to cross. Good
night.

What does she mean by this question? From the nature of the duologue, it would seem Mr Nev is at first naive to the plot against her, but once he senses something might be awry, tries to invite her into his confidence. But I am still intrigued by Catherine's exact question.

Mr. Nev is an insurance agent, who will likely receive a commission for a successful policy sale and possibly a promotion. However, Mr. Nev is also suspicious of this policy: typically a life insurance policy is established with the policy holder's involvement, so it looks suspicious when the holder is not involved at all.
Catherine, meanwhile, wants to stall for time because she also finds the policy irregular. In fact, once she realises that Mr. Nev is wary of the policy but hopes to proceed anyway, she ventures that Mr. Nev values the signing of the policy rather than her own wellbeing. Her use of the word "ambitious" here is hence a euphemism for his desire to benefit at any cost, including her own; his desire to benefit within the company, rather than to maintain for her wellbeing.
